# C# How can we expand the scope of enum flags?

Tags: c#, enums

I am using Enum Flags to indicate the status value.

but i Found out that this has a int range

so the following errors occur.

I want to add the enum status value, what should i do?

[image]

Comment: This smells pretty bad. Why your flag starts using powers of 2, then suddenly, for not reasons, the logic changes? How do you need more that 1000 values in your enum? If you can't name them to something more descriptive than Status1, status2 and so on, your enum is probably useless

Comment: consider using a dictionary rather than a Enum. Can be used similary but is more flexible when it comes to datatypes new Dictionary<string, uint64>;

Comment: You could try to change the base type to `long`, like `public enum eStatus : long`

Comment: Try `public enum eStatus : uint`

Comment: @Cid, this is false. All the flags shown are powers of two.

Comment: @LaurentGabiot right, this is hexadecimal, I guess I misread the code. However, it still smells bad

Comment: @Cid, Yes, my comment should have been more precise (and nice): only the part about the power of two is wrong (I was fooled at first too).

Comment: @LaurentGabiot no worries and thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

Your last enum value cannot be contained in the default integer representation used by enum: `int`.

You can check that: `0x80000000 > int.MaxValue` returns `true`.

So you must have your enum stored in a larger integer representation: `long`.

Like so:

```cs
[Flags]
public enum eStatus : long
{
    Status001 = 0x000000001,
    Status002 = 0x000000002,
    Status003 = 0x000000004,
    Status004 = 0x000000008,
    Status005 = 0x000000010,
    [...]
    Status1111 = 0x40000000,
    Status1112 = 0x80000000,
}
```

`Status1111` is a strange name, as you won't have more than 64 different possible values defined for the `eStatus` enum, as a `long` has only 64 digits in base 2.